# how to show data according to specific value

Tags: mysql, sql, .net, database

I have a table like this:

```
----------------------------------
f1.          :           f2
----------------------------------
sonu         :        monu
rakesh       :        sonu
vivek        :        monu
raju.        :        sonu
sonu         :        umesh
ramesh       :        sonu
-----------------------------------------
```

if we consider the specific value sonu then I want to fetch data like this...

```
----------------
 c1
------------------
monu
rakesh
raju
umesh
ramesh
---------------------
```

please help... 
thanks in advance....
I have submitted this question from mobile that's why it may be not easy to understand but please try for me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Curious problem.  Probably the easiest way is with `union all`:

```
select f2
from table t
where f1 = 'sonu'
union all
select f1
from table t
where f2 = 'sonu';
```

This is not the most efficient method for a large table, but it will work fine -- especially if you have indexes on each of the columns.

Answer (score 3):

You want all rows where f1 or f2 contain 'sonu', but the value of the other column?

```
select 
   case when f1 = 'sonu' then f2 else f1 end
from tab
where f1 = 'sonu' or f2 = 'sonu'
```

Comment: You mean `or f2 = ...`, and there is also a typo in the case (should be `='sonu'`). Still got my vote up.

Comment: @Zohar Peled: Thanks for spotting it, fixed it.